Arranging according to a dynamic number of columns in dplyr
Suppose I have the dataframe:
data = data.frame(A = c(3,2,1), B = c(2,1,1), C = c(1,2,1))

I would like to arrange the data according to a variable number of columns. Perhaps:
arranging_columns <- c('B')

...OR...
arranging_columns <- c('C', 'A') # *(ie, first arrange by C, then by A)*

I do not know how many columns I want to arrange by. Perhaps 1 column, perhaps 2 columns.
How can I achieve this using the dplyr::arange(...) function?
I have tried to pass a vector of arranging_columns to the function dplyr::arrange(...) and then to somehow unwrap this vector into multiple arguments, like:
arranging_columns <- c('C', 'B')
arranged <- dplyr::arrange(data, {arranging_columns})

Desired output:
A  B  C
1  1  1
3  2  1
2  1  2

But I just get an error saying:
Error in `dplyr::arrange()`:
ℹ In argument: `..1 = arranging_columns`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be size 3 or 1, not 2.


across() should do the trick.
arranged <- dplyr::arrange(data, dplyr::across(all_of(arranging_columns)))

arranged

>   A B C
> 1 1 1 1
> 2 3 2 1
> 3 2 1 2


arranged <- dplyr::arrange(data, dplyr::across(all_of(arranging_columns)))
arranged

A B C
1 1 1 1
2 3 2 1
3 2 1 2

